# Different object colors on SceneKit for iOS and macOS Catalyst app with same code

Tags: ios, swift, macos, scenekit, mac-catalyst

Here is the Swift code for generating the scene. It puts an image on a plane as texture (shortened for clarity):

```
func sceneSetup() {

    self.scene = SCNScene()

    let image = self.medImageSequenz.imageFromDicom(0)
    let width = image!.size.width
    let height = image!.size.height
    let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)

    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.isDoubleSided = true
    material.diffuse.contents = image
    planeGeometry.firstMaterial = material

    let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)
    self.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)

    self.allGeometries.append(planeGeometry)
    self.allNodes.append(planeNode)

    self.sceneView.scene = self.scene
    self.sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    self.sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
    self.sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}
```

The image is a black and white UIImage.

On Xcode I compile it for iPhone, iPad and Mac (Catalyst). On the native iOS devices and Simulators it works great, but on the Mac Catalyst app the image is shown in color red.

**On Mac:**

[image]

**On iPhone:**

[image]

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/40058657/3564632 ?

Comment: Hi Denis,
thanks a lot. That was the solution:

material.diffuse.textureComponents = .red

Comment: No problem, in this case I think this seems as a duplicate question for which there is already an answer, maybe you can delete it to not create confusion.